How to prevent CSS transition from playing on-load in Safari?
I'm trying to implement a simple CSS translate transition that slides the content in and out. It works perfectly in Chromium-based browsers, but the transition plays on-load in newer versions of Safari.

Reproduction site: https://safari-transition-bug.netlify.app/
Reproduction video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ySShpiWXltZWAoUOfmGrttCOGLttXcrG/view
Reproduction code (although it probably won't happen here, in the Stack Overflow sandbox):



document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('open')
})
main {
  background: green;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

main.open {
  transform: none;
}
<main>content</main>
<button>toggle</button>




This only happens in the Safari browser of my colleague, though:

Sonoma 14.5 (23F79), Safari Version 17.5 (19618.2.12.11.6) — ✅ works as expected
Ventura 13.6.8 (22G820), Safari Version 17.6 (18618.3.11.11.7, 18618) — ❌ transition glitches

How could I fix this issue? Since it appears to happen only in the newer browser version (17.6), perhaps it's a browser regression?

Have you tried wrapping your code in a load, readystatechange or DomContentLoaded event listener for the window, maybe checking the document.readyState equals 'changed'? I am unable to test with Safari at the moment, but may be worth a try.
